# How to use aliases with `watch` command?

Tags: bash, alias, watch

I have some bash aliases in my `~/.bashrc`, but they're not available within a `watch` command.  Normally, I would `source ./some_script.sh` which uses these aliases, but am having trouble figuring out how to do that with the `watch` command.

```
$ watch "my-alias"
Every 2.0s: my-alias

sh: 1: my-alias: not found
```

```
watch -x bash -c "my-alias"
Every 2.0s: my-alias

sh: 1: my-alias: not found
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

aliases are enabled in *interactive* shells, so try this:

```bsh
watch -x bash -ic "my-alias"
# .............^
```

Comment: That's it!  An extra option on `bash`, not `watch`.  I found I had to add an additional bit to make sure the interactive shell didn't exit with an error.  So my working usage is ``watch --interval 10 --exec /bin/bash -ic "my-alias || true"``

Comment: in case of zsh: `watch -x zsh -ic "my-alias"`